# Material-UI class name collisions

Tags: material-ui, lerna

I'm building a MUI-based component library for use on multiple internal sites, using Lerna to manage the package for local development.  We're having some issues with the class names colliding.  For example:

MyComponent.jsx

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    root: { 
    ...
    }
})

export const MyComponent = props => {
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            Hello SO
        </div>
    );
}
```

```
import { MyComponent } from 'my-library';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    root: { 
    ...
    }
})

export const MyView = props => {
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}> // classes.root === "makeStyles-root-1"
            <MyComponent /> // root class is named "makeStyles-root-1
        </div>
    );

}
```

This is causing problems due to some classes being overridden by the name collisions.

Comment: This most likely means that your app is ending up with two copies of Material-UI. I would recommend that Material-UI be a peer dependency in your component library.

Comment: It currently is, but it's also a devDependency - could that be what's causing the problem as well?

Comment: Not sure, but the key thing to check is whether or not Material-UI ends up being part of the build output for the component library.

Comment: That fixed it, thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Had written about it in detail [here](https://maneetgoyal.medium.com/handling-duplicate-bundling-of-materialui-with-webpack-in-monorepos-68835502e8a3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving MUI to be ONLY a peer dependency (instead of devDep and peer) resolved the problem.